# DELETE USING in gorm?

Tags: go-gorm

The title pretty much said it all.

In Postgre we have `DELETE FROM ... USING ... WHERE ...`

In gorm, I can not see that option any where. I try to avoid sub select as much as possible

Comment: i think official doc has enough example https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html

Comment: But like I said, no DELETE ... USING ...

Answer (score 0):

Here i have used [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/) and used [db.Raw()](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Raw-SQL) function to run  `DELETE FROM ... USING ... WHERE ...`  command

I have  created 2 table of **customer** and **owner**  in *postgresql*  inserted data manually using **psql cli**
Before running any Golang program 
**customer** table :
[image]
**owner** table :
[image]

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)


type customer struct  {
    Id int `gorm:"id"`
    First_name string `gorm:"first_name"`
    Last_name string `gorm:"last_name"`
    Email string `gorm:"email"`
    Gender string `gorm"gender"`
    Ip_address string `gorm:"ip_address"`
}

func main () {
    dburl:= "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432"

    db,err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dburl),&gorm.Config{})
    if err !=nil {
        log.Fatalln("error connnection")
    }
    // db.Exec("DELETE customer using owner WHERE customer.first_name = owner.first_name ")
    var s customer
    db.Raw("DELETE FROM customer using owner WHERE customer.first_name = owner.first_name ").Scan(&s)

}
```

After running this *Golang* code **first_name** field is deleted from **customer** table :
[image]

Comment: I'm aware of the Raw() function as well, but doing this you will lose Soft delete ability of gorm, you have to write WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL manually